# How do you remove the underline beneath a hyperlink when using Microsoft Word to create HTML?

Tags: html, hyperlink, ms-word

I'm using Microsoft Word 2010 on Windows to create an HTML website.

I want to use text as a logo, yet have the logo be a hyperlink that can be clicked on.

I can remove the underline from the text, and it disappears when I am viewing the text through Microsoft Word. However, when I view the same HTML page from a web browser, the text remains underlined.

How can I suppress the underline of the hyperlink, using Microsoft Word to create the page, so that the underline is not present when the site is viewed from a web browser?

My team only uses Microsoft Word, and other people change the file, through Word, quite often.

Comment: All I can say is: get a better html editor.  Word adds all sorts of junk you don't need or want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS, put this between your html head tags :

```
<style type="text/css">
A:link {text-decoration: none}
</style>
```